# Ploty.js graph not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

After using Plotly.js to create a stack bar graph, I noticed that it doesn't respond to different screen widths. How can the graph be made responsive to resize automatically fitting the screen width?

I tried using the following, but it didn't work:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    Plotly.Plots.resize('myDiv');
};
```

```js
var trace1 = {
    x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
    y: [20, 14, 23, 20, 14, 23, 34, 26],
    marker: {
        color: ['rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)']
    },
    name: 'Item 1',
    type: 'bar'
};

var trace2 = {
    x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
    y: [12, 18, 29, 12, 18, 29, 24, 22],
    marker: {
        color: ['rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)']
    },
    name: 'Item 2',
    type: 'bar'
};

var trace3 = {
    x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
    y: [12, 18, 29, 12, 18, 29, 24, 22],
    marker: {
        color: ['rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)']
    },
    name: 'Item 3',
    type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
    barmode: 'stack'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set autosize to True in your layout, then set the x and y axis to autorange via the relayout method. i.e.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
  y: [20, 14, 23, 20, 14, 23, 34, 26],
  marker: {
    color: ['rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)', 'rgba(0,152,212,0.5)']
  },
  name: 'Item 1',
  type: 'bar'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
  y: [12, 18, 29, 12, 18, 29, 24, 22],
  marker: {
    color: ['rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)', 'rgba(0,152,212,1)']
  },
  name: 'Item 2',
  type: 'bar'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D ', 'Category E', 'Category F', 'Category G', 'Category H'],
  y: [12, 18, 29, 12, 18, 29, 24, 22],
  marker: {
    color: ['rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)', 'rgba(0,54,136,1)']
  },
  name: 'Item 3',
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  barmode: 'stack',
  autosize: true // set autosize to rescale
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

// update the layout to expand to the available size
// when the window is resized
window.onresize = function() {
    Plotly.relayout('myDiv', {
        'xaxis.autorange': true,
        'yaxis.autorange': true
    });
};
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. Size stays the same.

Comment: @MacaronLover - eh? Click Run Code snippet -> then full page. Clearly the graph resizes to fill the full page width...

Comment: No worries - had me confused then :)